# MVC 5 Defining Sitemap Nodes with Action Filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitemap, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to define sitemap nodes with action filters, for example:

```
[SitemapUrl(Frequency = Frequency.Monthly, Priority = 0.9)]
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

This will generate the following:

```
<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/home/about</loc>
  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
  <priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
```

And it will be added to a collection that contains all the sitemap nodes, to be generated to a sitemap.xml when needed...

I'm thinking like the same behavior we use the "RouteAttribute".

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do at the `StartUp` class:

Suppose you have a simple attribute:

```
public class SitemapUrlAttribute : Attribute
{
    public double Priority {get;set;}
    public  SitemapUrlAttribute(double priority) { Priority = priority; }
}
```

In the startup class do as below to get all actions with this attribute:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var controllerActionlist = asm.GetTypes()
    .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                        BindingFlags.Public))
    .Where(m => !m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute),
        true).Any())
    .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttribute<SitemapUrlAttribute>() != null)
    .Select(
        x =>
            new
            {
                Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name,
                Area = x.DeclaringType.FullName,
                Action = x.Name,
                ReturnType = x.ReturnType.Name,
                Priority = x.GetCustomAttribute<SitemapUrlAttribute>().Priority
            })
    .ToList();
```

Now you have the list of controllers with your Priority data in a list:

Here is the code for saving the data in xml file:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
foreach (var action in controllerActionlist)
{
    var url = urlHelper.Action(action.Action, action.Controller, new {area = action.Area});
    var priority = action.Priority;

    if (something.DoesNotExist(url, priority))
    {
        Add(url, priority);
    }
}
```

I dont know how you will be saving and checking for an item if it does exists because this will be something custom but I think the next step is pretty easy.
If you have anything unclear just let me know!

Comment: Thanks, but how do you get the RouteValues or QueryString by reflection?

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection when you can easily use UrlHelper ?

Comment: I needed the query string parameters in the action for some sitemap URL's, anyways I solved it, by modifying to this: ` new
                        {
                            Action = x.Name,
                            Controller = x.DeclaringType?.Name.Replace("Controller", ""),
                            RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(x.GetParameters().ToDictionary(key => key.Name, value => value.DefaultValue)),
                            Priority = x.GetCustomAttribute<SitemapUrlAttribute().Priority
                        }) `